# How to delay start date of new job?

Tags: communication, new-job, germany, startup, start-date

I'm set to join a small tech start up in January 2023 but because of a health problem I need to delay my start date by at least one month so I can get treatment. How do I achieve this safely in this climate, and what are the risks?

I have already accepted the offer and signed the contract.

Comment: This: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/189043/can-i-delay-my-start-date was asked the other day and seems to be the same question? the only difference being the reason is for health.

Comment: I wonder why people didn't ask this question to their employer, seems easier to me...

Comment: @TheDemonLord, No, the question is completely different. In the question you linked to, the OP could have asked and accepted a "No" (since the OP didn't really need to delay). But if the reason is medical, that's a completely different reason. For instance, if the OP has a small cancer or something that needs to get removed, that could give the startup pause, and the start up might try to get rid of the OP before they even start the job.

Comment: @Duzii2, Honestly, I think the risks are great and you should probably consult with an employment lawyer that specializes in discrimination. That might cost you a few hundred dollars, but it's probably worth the peace of mind. Also, you may want to mention which country/state you're in.

Comment: Where in the world do you work? Where I live, you do not need to delay your start date, you just announce you need sick leave. Any sick leave certified by a doctor has to be acknowledged and sick leave is a protected reason that you cannot get fired for. Is that different in your country and if so which country is it?

Comment: @nvoigt I think that asking for sick leave during my probabtionary period would be bad for me

Comment: It is up to them what they do, but that looks hellish bad. They will think this: if that is the beginning, what to expect from you later? Your only way to fix it if there is really to problem with you a year long.

Answer (score 3):

Call your contact at the company, either your boss or the HR. Tell them you will be on sick leave. It would be good to have at least a somewhat specific date. For example "I will have to undergo a procedure on January 4th and the doctor told me that recovery can take up to four weeks". You don't need to get specific about what that procedure is.

Please note that you don't *ask* for sick leave in Germany. This is not a favor they do you or something they would need to approve. You are entitled to it. You **will be** on sick leave. Period. Maybe be polite and say you are sorry this happened. But that's it.

Make sure you have an "Arbeitsunfähigkeitsbescheinigung" (commonly abbreviated "AU" or called "gelber Schein" ("yellow slip", because the paper used to be yellow, don't be surprised, it is pink-ish now) for any day you miss. You get this certificate from your doctor. It is not uncommon to get that in stretches, lets say you get one for the procedure and the week after, and then another for a week and then another for a week and then maybe one for two days and then you go back to work if the doctor deems you fit to do so.

Your employer *does not* pay you if you get sick in the first four weeks of your employment. Instead, the health insurance will pay you.

So don't propose to move your start date. It will do nothing for your employer, who will not pay you either way, and only cheat you out of your benefits with the health insurance. Because if you are unemployed of your own free will, you will get nothing.

This *should* be just a little administrative issue. Germany has rules for it. If anybody at that company gives you anything else than a "best wishes/hope you get well soon/don't worry about it" reply, this would be *highly* unprofessional and I would reconsider working there altogether.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. I will let you know how it goes after I get my sick note from my doctor. P.S. How do you know so much about German employment?

Comment: @Duzii2 : Hanover, Germany? (...says the profile page :))

Comment: I've been in the workforce in Germany for 20+ years and I have had some training to teach apprentices, which includes all the rules and regulations of everyday workplace incidents.

Comment: Also, maybe I'm wrong but I thought that in Germany the employer pays your salary during the first 6 weeks of sick leave, then your health insurance pays your salary after 6 weeks of sick leave?

Comment: Is it okay if I email my new boss instead of calling? I received a new email from him so I think it's best to break this news in my reply to his email.

Comment: Sure, everything that leaves a "paper trail" is easier to work with. Emails can be forwarded to HR to do the administrative work, a phonecall would need note taking.

Comment: @Duzii2 That is correct, normally the employer pays the first six weeks. Unless it's less then four weeks into your job. Then it's the health insurance for the first four weeks, after that the employer and health insurance again as normal.

Comment: Wow, I never knew about the health insurance paying 100% of salary if sick leave is taken in the first four weeks of employment. Are there any conditions with this? It seems like a win-win for both employee and employer.

Comment: I should mention that I am unemployed since leaving my last job in October and have been receiving unemployment benefits 1 for one month now. Does this change anything with regards to my insurance paying my salary for the first 4 weeks of employment I spend on sick leave?

Comment: No, it does not change anything, but if you get benefits now and would continue to get them if you were not employed, you may want to calculate which is better. Please note that health insurance *does not* pay 100% of your salary, you will get "Krankengeld", the same benefit you would get if you were on sick leave for longer than 6 weeks. If you had no paycheck from your new company yet, it will be based on your last full contribution from your old job. If I remember correctly it's 70%, but you should check that with your insurance.

Comment: Since "ALG I" (unemployment benefits 1) is roughly 60%, I think you'd still be better off with health insurance. On the other hand, if it turns out that starting later would be less paperwork for all involved (for exxample you don't need to have doctors certificates), it might be worth it. That is your decision to make.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful advice. Based on your experience, what is my risk of losing this job if I ask to start a month later?

Comment: In my experience basically zero. Normal notice periods after probation in Germany are 6 weeks minimum, up to 6 months depending on how long you work there. So there is zero chance they would even get a replacement for you if they wanted. If they start looking now, they are looking at getting someone in March at best. They also invested time and money in finding you, they already finalized all the paperwork, nobody throws that away for a 4 weeks wait with no costs. But there are no 100% guarantees in life. They could be unreasonable jerks, no way to say for sure.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update you about this. My new boss said it's fine and that it comes in handy for them.