# How to approach meeting with new boss after I delayed start date due to medical reasons

Tags: communication, new-job, germany, start-date

I was set to start a new job, but had to postpone [due to medical reasons](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/189054/how-to-delay-start-date-of-new-job).

New boss scheduled a short meeting after postponing my January start date by a month.

Should I be worried and if he asks do I have to tell him exactly what the medical issue is?

He hasn't sent me the contract with the amended date and I'm still to receive work equipment. I'm hoping I will receive both in this short meeting.

P.S.
Is there anything I should prepare for before heading into this meeting?

Comment: So your boss postponed the start date? Or did you postpone the start date? This is not made very clear. If you postponed it without a contract signed sealed and delivered then you might not have a start date...

Comment: @SolarMike I requested a delayed start date so I could get treatment and my new boss said no problem. The original contract was signed for 01/01/2023.

Comment: @LoremIpsum are you saying that I shouldn't mention anything related to the medical issue?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I need to undergo procedures /treatments so requested a delayed start date which my new boss responded to by saying "No worries, it actually comes in handy".

Comment: @LoremIpsum I delayed due to undergoing a medical procedure

Comment: @JoeStrazzere because employers don't care about employees. I am just a number that can and will be replaced anytime it's convenient. It's also private and does me no good to divulge private medical information to an employer, they are not my friends, in fact it would likely be damaging to me. Yes, this is all directly related to the time off I took last year.

Comment: Did you postpone on your own? So you have not started yet? Or did you officially start, but are on sick leave? Is the meeting in person? Do you currently have a contract signed and what does it say?

Comment: "Should I be worried, and if he asks, do I have to tell him exactly what the medical issue is?" - If you don't feel comfortable sharing, you are within your legal rights, to just not answer the question.  Some people feel comfortable sharing an abridged version with their supervisor, while others feel comfortable sharing more, it's entirely up to you.

Comment: @nvoigt I emailed my new boss asking him to postpone by 1 month and he replied sayinf "No worries, it comes in handy“. I have not started. The meeting is in person. The signed contract I have is for the previous start date which was 01/01/2023. I didn't receive a new contract with a new start date.

Answer (score 3):

> New boss scheduled a short meeting after postponing my January start
> date by a month.
>
> Should I be worried and if he asks do I have to tell him exactly what
> the medical issue is?

You asked for a delay in your start date due to your medical issues, so most likely your boss just wants to find out your progress toward actually starting.

You don't have to state the medical issue, but it would seem foolish to be opaque about it, particularly if this is the same serious sickness that caused you to take substantial time off last year.

If I were the hiring manager, and you still aren't ready to start after the delay, I'd be worried and would start to line up a "Plan B".

> Is there anything I should prepare for before heading into this
> meeting?

Just be prepared to talk, be honest, and be open.